# Can't get 100% accept rate (glitch?)

Tags: support, accepted-answer, closed-questions, accept-rate

Hi there, my accept rate on SO is 94%, my username is 'Tom Gullen'.  I've been through all my questions and accepted answers on all of them as far as I can tell.

I think the reason it's not 100% is when I first joined SO, I asked a closed question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039127/powerpoint-2003-change-picture-closed

As far as I can tell this is affecting my accept rate, is there any way to not include closed/moved questions from your accept rate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[What's the point of a system registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327491/whats-the-point-of-a-system-registry)

It's already on 100%. Maybe you were still looking at a cached value? The accept rate is namely not updated realtime.
[alt text http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/1046/100perc.jpg](http://img137.imageshack.us/img137/1046/100perc.jpg)

Closed (and migrated) questions are already not taken in accept rate. Also see [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/).

Comment: I've done a hard refresh it's still showing as 94%, I've tried in 3 browsers as well.  I'll wait a few days then see if it changes :)

Comment: +1 for a "100" that looks like "IOU" and the joys of freehand.

Comment: @Lady: Ugh, thank you for "meta"-ing my answer :D

Comment: The image is dead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a faster way to find the questions for which you haven't accepted an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0+wiki%3A0

In your case the only one is indeed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039127/powerpoint-2003-change-picture-closed)